# Saving timestamps in Postgres based on Java dates

Tags: java, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a Postgres database with a table that contains a timestamp (`timeOfProcessing        TIMESTAMP`).

I have a Java datetime value (`java.util.Date dateTime`) and want to store its value in that timestamp field (without time zone).

When I do it using the query

`"INSERT INTO mytable(..., timeOfCreation, ...) VALUES(..., to_timestamp(" + Long.toString(dateTime.getTime()) + "),...)"`

and then read the saved value (`SELECT timeOfCreation FROM mytable`), they are different (`resultSet.getTimestamp(...).getTime()` is not equal to `dateTime.getTime()`).

How do I need to change the insert statement in order for the datetime to be stored correctly?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When inserting, instead of using `(dateTime).getTime()`, use an SQL timestamp object: `new java.sql.Timestamp((dateTime).getTime())`

Comment: @Sarief quite simply don't use an ORM. Embrace SQL and steer away from ORM monstrosities.