# convert a unix timestamp to a postgres equivalent timestamp in java

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a field in postgres

```
Column     |            Type          
created_at    | timestamp without time zone
```

I have a unix timestamp stored in long in Java

```
long createdAtTime = data.getcreatedAtTime();
```

I want to convert it to timestamp in java so that I can store with activejdbc into postgres

I tried the following

```
Date convertedTime = new Date(createdAtTime*1000L);
record.set("created_at", convertedTime);
record.saveIt();
```

But I get the following error:

```
Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.util.Date. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
```

Should I be using a different way to convert the date first?

Comment: You need to use a `java.sql.Timestamp` not a `java.util.Date`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most recommended way to store time in PostgreSQL using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627289/what-is-the-most-recommended-way-to-store-time-in-postgresql-using-java). And [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132219/saving-timestamps-in-postgres-based-on-java-dates). And others.

Comment: BTW, you should be using TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, not WITHOUT. Per [post by David E Wheeler](http://justatheory.com/computers/databases/postgresql/use-timestamptz.html) (Postgres expert).

Answer (score 0):

```
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(createdAtTime*1000L); 
record.set("created_at", convertedTime);
record.saveIt();
```

Instead of util you have tried with java.sql.Date.
Its a native type of SQL.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. A [java.sql.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) is intended for a date-only value without time-of-day. Not what the Question demands.

Comment: `java.sql.Date` will truncate the time.

Comment: @BoristheSpider we can use for that java.sql.Timestamp

Comment: @BasilBourque How can this is wrong answer. We can use java.sql.Date or java.sql.TimeStamp for dates in database

Comment: @SivaKumar A java.sql.Date sets its internal time to 00:00:00 as a hack to pretend to be a date-only without a time-of-day. The user's question is for tracking moment when data is created. **Your answer loses data**, namely the time-of-day portion of the Timestamp in the database. I would call an answer that needlessly loses data to be incorrect. Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes. But in SQL We can use java.sql.Date instead of java.util.Date. sql date only contain date-only. So We can use java.sql.TimeStamp for java.util.Date. java.util.Date can be used  other sql purpose.

Comment: @SivaKumar No, `java.sql.Date` *pretends* to represent a date-only value without a time-of-day and without a time zone, while in fact it contains both. By inheriting from `java.util.Date` (a *horrible* design flaw), this class is actually a count of milliseconds from 1970-01-01T00:00Z *plus* a fraction of a second in nanoseconds. This leads to all kinds of confusion and trouble. **Never use `java.sql.Date`** — now replaced by `java.time.LocalDate`. Furthermore, as I first commented, this Answer fail to address the Question which asks about moments not date-only.

Answer (score 0):

## Incompatible types

> I have a field in postgres …
>
> timestamp without time zone …

…and…

> I have a unix timestamp stored in long in Java
>
> long createdAtTime = data.getcreatedAtTime();

This is a contradiction.

The SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` purposely lacks any indicator of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). As such, this type does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. This type represents *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours, the range of time zones around the globe.

If you are trying to track specific moments, use the other SQL-standard type, `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. In Postgres, all values of this type are stored in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (an offset of zero). If you pass a value indicating some other offset or time zone, Postgres adjusts the value to UTC before storing.

When retrieving a value from a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` in Postgres, you are ***always* getting a value in UTC**. Unfortunately, some well-intentioned tools or drivers sitting between you and the database may decide the dynamically apply a time zone to the value. While well-intentioned, I consider this quite the anti-feature. This behavior creates the illusion of a time zone stored in the database while in fact **Postgres only stores UTC in this type**.

> Date convertedTime = new Date(createdAtTime*1000L);

The `java.util.Date` class is terrible, poorly designed and flawed. Never use this class nor its siblings, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and such. These are all legacy now, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

### `Instant`

The `Instant` class takes over for `java.util.Date`. Both classes represent a moment in UTC, though `Instant` has a finer resolution of nanoseconds versus milliseconds.

> unix timestamp stored in long in Java

If you have a count of whole seconds from the epoch reference of the first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, convert to an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1_539_555_140L ) ;
```

Tip: Do not make a habit of tracking time as a count-from-epoch. This is ambiguous (different systems use different resolutions and different epoch references), error-prone, and makes debugging/logging treacherous. Use *java.time* objects and standard ISO 8601 strings for representing date-time values.

Your JDBC driver may be able to accept an `Instant`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

Retrieval:

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

### `OffsetDateTime`

If not supporting `Instant`, use convert to `OffsetDateTime`. Any JDBC 4.2 or later driver is required to support `OffsetDateTime`.

`OffsetDateTime` represents a date and time-of-day with an offset-from-UTC. In contrast, `Instant` is fixed at UTC, serving as a basic building-block class in *java.time* framework. Also, `OffsetDateTime` is more flexible with abilities such as generating strings in various formats versus `Instant` using only standard ISO 8601 format.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval:

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

…or…

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ).toInstant() ;
```

### `LocalDateTime`

If you are *not* trying to represent moments, such as database type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, use the `LocalDateTime` class.

But if you are thinking use of these types is somehow avoiding the work of using time zones in tracking moments, you are sorely mistaken. This is a “pay now or pay later” situation: Either learn basic date-time concepts and handling practice now, or desperately wrestle with a horrible mess of failed data later.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I see that your Database column stores value as time stamp without time zone,
why don't you try this

```
Timestamp current = Timestamp.from(Instant.now());
record.set("created_at", current);//I don't know if you might need to parse
record.saveIt();
```